# How do I give ECS containers access to a private git repo?

Tags: git, ssh, deployment, key, amazon-ecs

I looked at this article: [Github Deploy Keys](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys)

From what I have read, it treats clients like it is a stationary machine that always has an ssh setup to clone the repo. In ECS, however the client machine changes variably. Do I have to setup ssh each time on each container ?

My question is coming from an AWS point of view, is there some kind of "role " that can be set so that whenever we deploy a service, it has read access to a private github repo?

Comment: When you say ECS client machine, are you referring to the host EC2 instances that powers the cluster? Also you want to access a repo from host machine or from a container? What is your usecase?

Comment: Embed the "role" in your containers, either a startup script or edit the Dockerfile

Comment: Hi Ashan,  my use case is that the code running inside the container needs to make a call to the github repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> that the code running inside the container needs to make a call to the github repo.

That means the container must start with a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) of a `.ssh/id_rsa`/`.ssh_id_rsa.pub` allowing the container to authenticate itself to GitHub, as a collaborator.

SSH is not the only way to access a private repo: mounting a PAT (Personal Access Token) would allow the container to use an HTTPS URL.

But in both case, the container needs to mount the files needed for a proper authentication in order to access the remote private repo.

Answer (score 2):

You can store private key content in [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/). Then you can access it with [AWS CLI](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/secretsmanager/get-secret-value.html) like:

```sh
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:foocompany:secret:secret-name-X1cUDA | python -c 'import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)["SecretString"]' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

You may need setup secret permissions similar to

```json
{ "Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
            "Principal": {"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::foocompany:user/user"},
            "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:238513131754:secret:arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:foocompany:secret:secret-name-X1cUDA"
        }
    ]
}
```